# absolute convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to figure out of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-1^n}{n}-\frac{-1^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ converges absolutely. I know that we use the ratio test to see if a series converges absolutely, but im having a hard time with figuring out what $a_{n}$ would be?

Comment: It is hard to decipher your statement as the parentheses don't match. Are you trying to ask wheter $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n} -\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)$$ converges absolutely?  
It would also be useful if you would use MathJax in your questions. See [the tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: yes, that is what I am asking.

Comment: @Lydia: You really should learn to accept answers and learn to upvote answers that you find helpful. You are more likely to get nice answers that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the $k$th partial sum is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n} -\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)= -1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{(-1)^k}{k} + \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}
$$ 
This is a telescoping sum. Unless I made a mistake, this should show you that the series is convergent.

Note that
$$
\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n} -\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right) = (-1)^n(\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1})
$$
Hence you get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert a_n \vert = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1}.
$$
You just have to dertermine if this series is convergent. If it is, then your original series is absolutely convergent. If it is divergent, then your original series is conditionally convergent.

Comment: Using this limit laws, this would more or less be the same as 1/n which is a harmonic series therefore it doesn't converge. Is this correct?

Comment: @Lydia: That is correct.